# Disk and stick Collision involving conservation of angular momentum

Tags: momentum

A 2.0kg disk traveling at 3.0m/s strikes a 1.0kg stick of length 4.0m that is lying flat on nearly frictionless ice. The disk strikes at the endpoint of the stick, at a distance r=2.0m from the center of the stick. Assume the collision is elastic and the disk does not deviate from its original line of motion.

My question:

I understand that you have to use the conservation of linear, angular, and energy models in order to solve this problem. The issue I am having is setting up the angular momentum equation. This is what I have, but according to the book, I am wrong. Can somebody please tell me why!

Conservation of Angular Momentum: MdVdRi=MdVdRf+Is

---

Comment: Typo mistake in the last part. Iw(of the stick)*

Comment: Please use mathjax in writing equations